# How can pass predicate as variable to Expression<Func<T>>

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a `Get()` function in service layer:

**IEntityService:**

```
IEnumerable<T> GetAllQuerable(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
string includeProperties = "");
```

**EntityService:**

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAllQuerable(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "")
{
    return _repository.Get(filter, orderBy, includeProperties);
}
```

I commonly call this method with explicit predicate like this:

```
var result = _myModelService.Get(x => x.myPropery =="someValue").OrderByDescending(x => x.Date);
```

Now I want to pass predicate as variable to `Get()`. After looking for this I figured out that I can make a `Predicate<T>` but I still can 't pass predicate to `Get()` method.

Whats the best solution to pass a predicate as variable to `Expression<Func<T>>()` ?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you're trying to accomplish? What benefit would you get from using a `Predicate<T>`?

Comment: My goal is pass variable to `Get()` method. How can I do this with expression trees?

Comment: @user3748973 You pass in an expression tree, because that's what it's expecting.  It's not expecting a `Predicate`, so you can't pass a `Predicate` in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you create the variable using an expression tree, you should be able to pass it around all you like:

```
public IEnumerable<MyType> GetFromRepository(Expression<Func<MyType, bool>> filter)
{
    _myModelService.Get(filter)
                   .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date);
}

// later....

Expression<Func<MyType, bool>> myFilter = x => x.myProperty == "someValue";

GetFromRepository(myFilter);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really need an expression tree (for SQL), you can't cheat and make it call an opaque delegate.  EF has no way to convert a `Predicate<T>` to SQL.

You need to use expression trees everywhere.